# Call predefined number automatically on Android with Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am writing an app based on Augmented Reality using Unity3d, in my app i have a 3D-cube which is work as button, onclick it should automatically call a predefined number. How to create Plugin for Dialer in android, and how that plugin use in Unity3D??

How can i make a direct call from the app by clicking on Cube?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a call using unity on android is actually very simple, on button click execute this:

```
Application.OpenURL( "tel://[phone number]" )
```

Reference: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/button-to-make-phone-call.96227/

Comment: You're welcome :) Please consider accepting my answer so your question is not left unanswered :)

Comment: Hello, Jay. I have one more problem. I want to add Predefined Contact in contact list of Android Phone by clicking on cube in unity. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think unity has that functionality (well if it does, then I don't know how). I tried googling it but no relevant results.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you. :)
I also tried a lot.. but still didn't get any idea..
Thanks a lot for your valuable response... :)

Comment: Hello. Do you know how to detect 3 to 4 Target image from single app using Vuforia SDK in unity..!!!
If you know then please inform me..

Comment: You should make a separate question from this one since your question is entirely different. As of me, I never tried Vuforia SDK. Try posting another question and see if others can help you.